# Python How to Share Telnet Session between Parent and Subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, telnetlib

I have a parent process which executes a child process using `subprocess.Popen()`. Currently my parent process starts a new telnet session and my child process too starts a new session.

Is there a way by which I can prevent this new session from being created in the child? Something like the parent process sharing it's `telnetlib` object with the child process or a third python script starts the session and parent and child using it?

The **issue** I am facing is, I have around **20 child processes** which means **21 telnet sessions** which is taking a lot of time and I want to minimize this overhead.

Comment: Well, using `os.fork` you could easily share the telnet connection with all processes, but then you'd have to rework the way in which you are handling the children.

Comment: Yes, hence I am not using `os.fork` at all